# MVC Session Serialization Error.Unable to find assembly 'EntityFrameworkDynamicProxies

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, session, model-view-controller, serialization

I have a mvc commerce project. I use sessions for user login. For example I use membership information in session like this.Ofc Session is not null.

```
Member member=Session["MemberSuccess"] as Member
```

Also because of the pool time of shared hostings I use sql state session.It works fine at localhost. But when i upload it to the server it gives me an error like this;

```
Unable to find assembly 'EntityFrameworkDynamicProxies-DataLayer, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null'.
```

I don't know is there any relevance but my servers trust level is full. I use entity framework. And I keep edmx file in a seperate class library. Also I tried 
adding [Serializable] attiributes at classes under .tt file.

And here is the stack trace

```
[SerializationException: Unable to find assembly 'EntityFrameworkDynamicProxies-DataLayer, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null'.]
   System.Runtime.Serialization.Formatters.Binary.BinaryAssemblyInfo.GetAssembly() +3124514
   System.Runtime.Serialization.Formatters.Binary.ObjectReader.GetType(BinaryAssemblyInfo assemblyInfo, String name) +10830282
   System.Runtime.Serialization.Formatters.Binary.ObjectMap..ctor(String objectName, String[] memberNames, BinaryTypeEnum[] binaryTypeEnumA, Object[] typeInformationA, Int32[] memberAssemIds, ObjectReader objectReader, Int32 objectId, BinaryAssemblyInfo assemblyInfo, SizedArray assemIdToAssemblyTable) +120
   System.Runtime.Serialization.Formatters.Binary.__BinaryParser.ReadObjectWithMapTyped(BinaryObjectWithMapTyped record) +286
   System.Runtime.Serialization.Formatters.Binary.__BinaryParser.ReadObjectWithMapTyped(BinaryHeaderEnum binaryHeaderEnum) +57
   System.Runtime.Serialization.Formatters.Binary.__BinaryParser.Run() +581
   System.Runtime.Serialization.Formatters.Binary.ObjectReader.Deserialize(HeaderHandler handler, __BinaryParser serParser, Boolean fCheck, Boolean isCrossAppDomain, IMethodCallMessage methodCallMessage) +120
   System.Runtime.Serialization.Formatters.Binary.BinaryFormatter.Deserialize(Stream serializationStream, HeaderHandler handler, Boolean fCheck, Boolean isCrossAppDomain, IMethodCallMessage methodCallMessage) +186
   System.Web.Util.AltSerialization.ReadValueFromStream(BinaryReader reader) +937
   System.Web.SessionState.SessionStateItemCollection.ReadValueFromStreamWithAssert() +55
   System.Web.SessionState.SessionStateItemCollection.DeserializeItem(String name, Boolean check) +289
   System.Web.SessionState.SessionStateItemCollection.get_Item(String name) +19
   System.Web.SessionState.HttpSessionStateContainer.get_Item(String name) +11
   System.Web.HttpSessionStateWrapper.get_Item(String name) +14
   ASP._Page_Views_Shared__Layout_cshtml.Execute() +186
   System.Web.WebPages.WebPageBase.ExecutePageHierarchy() +198
   System.Web.Mvc.WebViewPage.ExecutePageHierarchy() +104
   System.Web.WebPages.WebPageBase.ExecutePageHierarchy(WebPageContext pageContext, TextWriter writer, WebPageRenderingBase startPage) +90
   System.Web.WebPages.<>c__DisplayClass7.<RenderPageCore>b__6(TextWriter writer) +230
   System.Web.WebPages.HelperResult.WriteTo(TextWriter writer) +10
   System.Web.WebPages.WebPageBase.Write(HelperResult result) +80
   System.Web.WebPages.WebPageBase.RenderSurrounding(String partialViewName, Action`1 body) +64
   System.Web.WebPages.WebPageBase.PopContext() +262
   System.Web.WebPages.WebPageBase.ExecutePageHierarchy(WebPageContext pageContext, TextWriter writer, WebPageRenderingBase startPage) +98
   System.Web.Mvc.RazorView.RenderView(ViewContext viewContext, TextWriter writer, Object instance) +255
   System.Web.Mvc.BuildManagerCompiledView.Render(ViewContext viewContext, TextWriter writer) +107
   System.Web.Mvc.ViewResultBase.ExecuteResult(ControllerContext context) +291
   System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeActionResult(ControllerContext controllerContext, ActionResult actionResult) +13
   System.Web.Mvc.<>c__DisplayClass1a.<InvokeActionResultWithFilters>b__17() +23
   System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeActionResultFilter(IResultFilter filter, ResultExecutingContext preContext, Func`1 continuation) +245
   System.Web.Mvc.<>c__DisplayClass1c.<InvokeActionResultWithFilters>b__19() +22
   System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeActionResultWithFilters(ControllerContext controllerContext, IList`1 filters, ActionResult actionResult) +176
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.<>c__DisplayClass2a.<BeginInvokeAction>b__20() +75
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.<>c__DisplayClass25.<BeginInvokeAction>b__22(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +99
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncResult`1.End() +50
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker.EndInvokeAction(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +44
   System.Web.Mvc.<>c__DisplayClass1d.<BeginExecuteCore>b__18(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +14
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.<>c__DisplayClass4.<MakeVoidDelegate>b__3(IAsyncResult ar) +23
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncResult`1.End() +55
   System.Web.Mvc.Controller.EndExecuteCore(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +58
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.<>c__DisplayClass4.<MakeVoidDelegate>b__3(IAsyncResult ar) +23
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncResult`1.End() +55
   System.Web.Mvc.Controller.EndExecute(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +48
   System.Web.Mvc.Controller.System.Web.Mvc.Async.IAsyncController.EndExecute(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +10
   System.Web.Mvc.<>c__DisplayClass8.<BeginProcessRequest>b__3(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +25
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.<>c__DisplayClass4.<MakeVoidDelegate>b__3(IAsyncResult ar) +23
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncResult`1.End() +55
   System.Web.Mvc.MvcHandler.EndProcessRequest(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +31
   System.Web.Mvc.MvcHandler.System.Web.IHttpAsyncHandler.EndProcessRequest(IAsyncResult result) +9
   System.Web.CallHandlerExecutionStep.System.Web.HttpApplication.IExecutionStep.Execute() +9651688
   System.Web.HttpApplication.ExecuteStep(IExecutionStep step, Boolean& completedSynchronously) +155
```

Comment: Apparently database objects has a grudge against defining as sessions

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try disabling proxy creation in your DbContext class:

```
context.Configuration.ProxyCreationEnabled = false;
```

Comment: I'll try and let you know. Thank you

Comment: Is this meant to be placed inthe constructor method of the context class?

Comment: @RickerSilva It could be, it depends on your requirements. If you always want some configuration to be applied everytime a context instance is made, then this is a viable option.

Comment: Yes, I didi it that way and it solved my problem. I was having an error right on home page load, and I'm no longer needing proxies in the project